# Decrease bottom footer area

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to decrease the bottom footer area inside a purchased web design template. The designer takes numerous days to answer any question if he answers them at all, this is why I'm looking for additional source for information.

I can attached a pdf of the area I'm trying to decrease , I also attached some information from the css style sheet, any help is appreciated, How do I attached the pdf, my website www.onesteptogether.com/topps

thanks

enter code here

```
/* footer */ 




#footer {
clear: both;
min-height: 100px;
padding:0 0 30px 0;
border-top:4px solid #333333;
background-color:#f0f0f0;


}
#footer .inner {
padding:20px;
border-bottom:1px solid #e1e1e1;
color:#666666;
background:none !important;



}
#footer .inner_top {
background:#ffffff !important;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
-khtml-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
border-bottom:4px solid #e1e1e1;
box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
position:relative;
top:-4px;
overflow:auto;
padding-top:15px;
}


.boxed #footer .inner_top {
top:0px;


}
#footer .column {
margin-bottom:15px;
min-height:348px;


}
#footer .column:first-child {
border-bottom:1px solid #e1e1e1;


}
#footer h4 {
color: #000000;
font-size: 21px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding:0 0 8px 0;
border-bottom:1px solid #e1e1e1;


}
#footer .column ul.footer_links {
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
```

Comment: Can you add some HTML please?

Comment: If I were to guess, `#footer`'s `min-height` can be changed

Comment: decrase min-height:348px; to whatewer you want on #footer .column. If you want to decrase below 100px see the comment above

Comment: And if you're really desperate for pixels, you can shave off some of the padding of `#footer .inner` too.